# Piping PCRE grep into sed

Tags: linux, bash, regex, grep, sed

I wanna sed this file, but the BRE in sed is not working as well as I hope.

What I have now is basically just :

```
$ cat Dungeon | grep -P -o '<\/.*?>'
```

My question is how do I sed this? I want to remove the pieces I have managed to grep. Alternatives are also welcomed; though if possible I want to know how to work this out too.

(Yes I am using regex on HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "PCRE sed" tool:

```
cat Dungeon | perl -pe 's/<\/.*?>//g'

perl -i -pe 's{</.*?>}{}g' Dungeon
```

Combining grep and sed is unlikely to happen; the two don't exchange enough context to pass existing matches with their position in the file. You could try `grep -b` to get the byte offsets of each match (and using them with *something else than sed* to remove the corresponding byte ranges from the file), or try transforming the `grep -o` output to a monster regex suitable for sed's POSIX Extended regular expressions (changing line breaks to pipes for `a|b|c` branch syntax, making sure to escape all regex special characters – which needs another 'sed' invocation on its own), but either would be much more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Works! thanks a lot! I would also like to ask for a explanation if that is alright

Comment: Well, it's just Perl – the Perl programming language has a `$variable =~ s/regex/replacement/` operator much like sed; it accepts PCRE-compatible regexes (as PCRE literally stands for "Perl-compatible"); and using `-p` will apply the provided Perl code for each input line, as a shortcut for a "while (read line) { run code; print line }" loop. (in this example the s/// operator works on the implicit $_ variable). See `man perlrun`.